# How do I store references to elements of a 2D array?

Tags: c#

I'm checking each element of a 2d array for specific conditionals.
If the element is true I want to check it's direct neighboring adjacent elements.
If the neighboring elements are false I want to keep track of them, lets call these "validElements". 
Once all elements have been checked I want to pick one of the validElements at random and make it true, then clear that collection of validElements and repeat this process an arbitrary amount of times.

I know how to check each element and their neighbors for the conditionals but i'm not sure the proper way to keep track of the references to elements that are considered "validElements". How should I keep track of this data?

```
public bool [,] Grid = new bool [3,3];

// lets make the middle element true so we have a starting point. 

Grid[Grid.GetLength(0) / 2, Grid.GetLength(1) / 2] = true;

for (int row = 0; row < Grid.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < Grid.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        if (Grid[row, col])
        {
            // if neighboring cells are false keep track of them somehow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a class that has a bool property, and an IsValid property. Make a 2D array of that. Or if you're into disco and flared trousers, make a parallel 2D flag array to store validity states for the first one.

Comment: Is the Grid expected to change? I mean, are the elements inside going to potentially change order? If not, you could make a list of coordinate pairs. Something like `var validElements = new List<(int x, int y)>()`. Then, whenever you find an element that matches your conditions, you do `validElements.Add((whateverRow, whateverCol))`. So, at the end of the loop, this variable will contain all valid elements and you'll be able to manipulate the elements at those coordinates however you want. If they might change order, then I would go with any of @EdPlunkett 's idea.

Comment: Thanks @CiprianVilcan Once the grid size is set it won't change, i'm using it to make a random path on a "map". the only requirement is that the new node has to connect to a adjacent true node. once I choose a random element in the list how would I apply it to the original array? Grid[x], [y] = Grid[[validElements[x], [validElements[y]]?

Comment: Added this conversation as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most basic solutions would be to create a list of coordinates where you'll store all the Xs and Ys where you found a valid element. So, before your

```
for (int row = 0; row < Grid.GetLength(0); row++)
```

add a

```
var validElements = new List<(int x, int y)>();
```

and instead of your

```
// if neighboring cells are false keep track of them somehow
```

do

```
if (/*some condition*/)
{
    validElements.Add((row, col));
}
```

Next, once the loop is done, you need to pick a random valid element and set it to true. You can do this by

```
var random = new Random();
var randValidElement = validElements[random.Next(validElements.Count - 1)]; 
// above line is assuming you have at least one valid element. 
// You should do a check if validElements.Count == 0 then do something
Grid[randValidElement.x, randValidElement.y] = true; // this is the final step
```